# linux 2 grub bootloader installed -

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, kali-linux, bootloader

i have both OS installed, Ubuntu 20.04 and the newest Kali version (wanted to try it out - now its just taking space ... lol) However, i have two grub bootloaders on my harddrive. Everything works fine, I just dont like the Kali Bootloader and i dont know how to set it to my old Ubuntu Bootloader. I tried some stuff but now im stuck, i got some information fro the Boot Info Script.

Boot Info Script - Results.txt: sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
Operating System:  Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

Hope you guys can help, Thanks !

Comment: GPT or MBR??, this changes everything.  If MBR, try setting the *active partition* to the one you want.  If GPT.. one of the other brainiacs will chime in.  I am not an expert with GPT.

Comment: i think its MBR, if i got the information right ?
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 94 for .

i tried fdisk fdisk/dev/sda5 to run in terminal and the message said:
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The old ext4 signature will be removed by a write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier...

Comment: Okay Solved !
Thanks Senor ! 
I just used the grub customizer and installed the bootloader on dev/sda1 :)

Comment: YEAH!  YEAH!  I am very happy that you got it working!!!